# How to "fit" two grids in a new window, extjs 4

Tags: layout, grid, window, extjs4.1

i'm trying to make a window containing two grid. It is impossible, in this case, to use

```
layout: fit,
```

So i had to give a try to the others options like: [Anchor, Columns, Vbox and Hbox](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html). The problem is that both the grid are very long and require more than the height of the page to be shown. I opted for the column layout as the grids are resized and all the results are shown, with vbox and hbox the grids are cut at the end of the window and you can not read any further.

However my bosses are not satisfied with the solution of the columns. Do you have any better idea to fit the two grids in a window? Do you have experience with an other method?

Just show me a link or speak about your solution.

Agnese

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fit` layout is only used for a single item that needs to fit exactly in the parent container.

[**VBox**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) layout is to layout the boxes vertically. You can use `flex` property to allocate space based on the need and the available viewing area.

You need to tell us what exactly you need it to look like to tell you concretely which layout to use. But here is an example based on your previous question with nested panels: **http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/6r7Dd/1/** - this revision contains a vbox with two panels (grids are also panels)

Use [**examples**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) to get ideas on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Your example is very helpful. Thank you!